# "The selected item is invalid" - NextJS + Laravel / 422 Error

Tags: laravel, postman, http-status-code-422

Well I have this problem...
I have created a new place record, and then I check that it exists.

[image]

So far so good, but now when I want to link it to some restaurant, it returns **422 Error.**

[image]

I was looking for some answer, but I don't understand what I did wrong.

This is my code:

```
    public function store(Request $request){

    $this->authorize('create', Feeding::class);

    $request->validate([
        'date' => 'required|date|max:255',
        'food' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'observation' => 'required|string',
        'quantityLunchs' =>'required|integer',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
        'artist_id' => 'required|exists:artists,id',
        'place_id' => 'required|exists:places,id',

    ], self::$messages);

    $feeding = Feeding::create($request ->all());
    return response() -> json($feeding, 201); //success
}
```

The headers I use in postman:

***Authorizaton***: Bearer token

***Accept:*** application/json

Any solutions?
Tank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved.

I had to replace here:

[image]

Becouse I want to link with feeding_places, no with places
Fiuuu!

Comment: Do not use images as they can go down and then the question makes no sense as you can't see the data because it was in an image... Copy paste the code...